# Subset of open set and subset of its bourdary is open

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a non-empty open set in $\mathbf{R}^2$ [with respect to the Euclidean topology] with bourdary $B$.

Is it possibile there exist a non-empty subsets $A^\prime \subseteq A$ and $B^\prime \subseteq B$ such that $A^\prime \cup B^\prime$ is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for any open set this is not possible...for an example if $D=${$x| |x|<1$} ..then it is not possible since any point of the boundary there exists no ndb contained in $D$.

but for some special case it is possible ... consider $A=D\(0,0)$ then $(0,0) \in B$ ...and $A \cup (0,0) =D$ is open in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: Why $(0,0) \in B$?

Comment: here $B$ is the boundary of $A'$ ... and (0,0) is a boundary point

Comment: Well, $B$ should be the bourdary of $A$, not the bourdary of $A^\prime$..

Comment: well, here I used some abuse of notation....

Comment: you carefully read the ans you will understand...

Comment: Now it works, well :)